# What problems can I solve with django middleware?

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner in django middleware. I used to write a visitor system via middleware and still did't get a problem which can be solved with a middleware. Could you describe any typical tasks with django middleware? And tasks where the middleware must have to be

Comment: I find it rather weird to reason that way. I think it is better to ask: what are common tasks I perform in every request (for example checking if the user is authenticated, then you move it to middleware to avoid to write this in every view.)

Comment: Okay, I can use decorators for example for every view or you will write business logic in middleware as in the view if user is authenticated?

Comment: you *can* write logic in the middleware that deals with the user, the point is that the middleware is processed for *each* request. There is typically not *much* logic that needs to be processed every time. So typically it is authentication, logging, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see middleware as a list of *implicit* decorators around every view. In short, middelware is thus used for **pre-processing requests**, and **post-processing responses**. It can also be used for example to perform diagnostics (measure the time between a request and a response).

Before a `HttpRequest` is processed by a specific view, and before the `HttpResponse` the view generates is sent to the client, middleware (can) interact with the request, or post-process the response.

A common example is an authentication system. By default this is middleware that is put in the `MIDDLEWARE` list in the settings. You probably frequently do something with `request.user`, but where does that attribute originates from? It is added to the `request` by [**`django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L16):

> ```
> class AuthenticationMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
>     def process_request(self, request):
>         assert hasattr(request, 'session'), (
>             "The Django authentication middleware requires session middleware "
>             "to be installed. Edit your MIDDLEWARE%s setting to insert "
>             "'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' before "
>             "'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'."
>         ) % ("_CLASSES" if settings.MIDDLEWARE is None else "")
>         request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
> ```

As you can see, it patches the `request`, by adding an attribute: `request.user = ...`. Without this middelware, a `HttpRequest` will not carry a (lazily fetched) user.

Another example of middleware could be a system that measures how long every view takes, and logs this to the console: when fetching the request, it for example attaches a timestamp to the request before it enters the view, and when it obtains the response, it looks how much time has passed.

Post-processing responses is possible as well. Imagine that you each time want to set a certain cookie in the HTTP response, then again middleware is definitely a good idea.

You could for example implement middleware that keeps track on how many times (each user) visits a certain page, and thus store that data somewhere (a file, memory, database, etc.).

Of course you could - strictly speaking - perform such actions in the view (or in a decorator of the view), but that would mean you need to add the decorator to all possible views that need this. Imagine if later on, you decide to no longer have users on your site, then you would have to remove the decorator (or even worse, code) from all these views. If you later want to log the performance of the views, you would need to add the decorator to all the views. This would not be elegant, you want to have some mechanism to do all these things without specifying these in (or at the top of) the views.

In general you can say that it carries out tasks that are performed on *all* request-response cycles (although the middelware can of course inspect the request/response, and decide to leave it untouched).

By adding a lot of middleware however you slow down the request-response path, hence if you for example have no authentication system, then it might be beneficial to throw out the related middleware that will - even if unused - still use some cycles to determine that it is not used. Although you can implement any Python function in Django middleware, in general middleware handles *simple* and *common* things.

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#middleware) has a section about developing your own middelware.

Answer (score 3):

Middleware are actions that take place between server- and client-side interactions. Essentially they are just functions that are executed when a request is received by the server before and after the main server logic happens. They are useful if you have some action or check (or set of actions/checks) that needs to be performed on every or most requests.

Authentication is a good example. You *could* perform an authentication check explicitly in every view function on your server, but that's not very DRY, it clutters the main logic of each view function, and what if you forget on a route? Instead, you can write a middleware that checks if the user is logged in. If they are, pass the request on a usual. If not, redirect them to the login page. Another example is Django's built-in [CSRF protection middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.csrf).

Decorators are another way to package functionality and add that functionality to functions without needing to rewrite the same code in each function that needs it. Middleware is pretty much the same idea except they are added automatically while decorators need to be added to each individual function, and this can get pretty cumbersome as the amount of functionality you need for each view increases. In a server decorators should only be used when the functionality provided is relatively unique (only needed by a few routes).

To be clear, there is nothing you can do with middleware that you can't without, but they provide much better structure for your code and make your server much more scaleable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you understand what Django's Middleware is. It's not something like [IBM's definition of middleware](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/middleware).

Django's middleware is much smaller in scope and allows you to perform tasks in between a browser request and the business logic - or the other way around - in between the business logic and the response to the browser - or both.

Typical tasks are:

- Put information on the request object before it gets to the view (see AuthenticationMiddleware for an example)
- Validate incoming requests
- Add headers to responses
- Intercept and reformat exceptions